# What does this(context, 0) mean AlertDialog source code

Tags: java, android, methods, this, android-alertdialog

I am learning the Android framework and wanted to create my own custom Dialog that allows me to pick a Date and Time at the same time. I am looking at the AlertDialog source code and the constructor calls the method this(context, 0). I am usually confused with the "this" reference. And am unsure of what it means here when called as a method.

Link to source: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/app/AlertDialog.java

```
protected AlertDialog(Context context) {
    this(context, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this(context, 0)` calls the following constructor in the AlertDialog class.

```
protected AlertDialog(Context context, @StyleRes int themeResId) {
    this(context, themeResId, true);
}
```

The above method creates an alert dialog that uses an explicit theme resource.
`this()` is used to call another constructor in a class.

Comment: I didn't realize that constructor only had a single argument and the call was two arugments. I thought it was calling itself recursively.

Answer (score 0):

`This` keyword refereed to the current class where you are working at this time.

`this(context, 0);` its actully calling the AlertDialog constructor which has two parameters.